# How I can paint a text background with spdlog?

Tags: c++, c++17, spdlog

I did a test with the {fmt} and was super easy to change background color, but I can't get the same with spdlog.
I can get the same result with spdlog, but is a weird code

```
fmt::print( bg( fmt::terminal_color::yellow ) | fg( fmt::terminal_color::black ), " {1:<{0}}\n", 120, "message" );  
        
spdlog::set_pattern( "%v" );
spdlog::info( "\033[43m\033[30m {1:<{0}} \033[m", 120, "message" );
```

Comment: That's VT100.  It's not weird at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to format your `spdlog` output using `fmt`, rather than having to specify the escape sequences yourself. For this, you can use the `fmt::format` function and use its output as a variable for `spdlog`:

```
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/fmt/bundled/color.h>

int main(){
    spdlog::info( "Printing a string formatted with fmt: {}",
        fmt::format(
            fmt::bg( fmt::terminal_color::yellow ) |
            fmt::fg( fmt::terminal_color::black ) |
            fmt::emphasis::bold,
            "message"
        )
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i would like to do

Comment: Glad to help. Please vote accordingly and accept the answer :)